# Using a CTE with = ANY

Tags: postgresql

Query:

```
WITH first_names AS (SELECT DISTINCT fname FROM voters) 
SELECT name 
from nicknames 
WHERE groupi = (
    SELECT nn.groupi 
    FROM nicknames AS nn 
    WHERE name = 'john'
) AND name != 'john' AND upper(name) = ANY(first_names);
```

Error:
`column "first_names" does not exist`

How do I make an array from a select and use it in a where statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing auxiliary statement names with columns here.  `first_names` is the name for the result provided by your `SELECT DISTINCT`, and `fname` is the name of the column contained within.

Not commenting on the correctness of your query overall, the corrected statement would be to use the correct column name.

```
WITH first_names AS (SELECT DISTINCT fname
                     FROM voters)
SELECT name
FROM nicknames
WHERE groupi = (
  SELECT nn.groupi
  FROM nicknames AS nn
  WHERE name = 'john'
) AND name != 'john' AND upper(name) = ANY (first_names.fname);
```

Answer (score 0):

[try JOIN instead of ANY](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91254/30035)

```
WITH first_names AS (SELECT DISTINCT fname FROM voters) 
SELECT name 
from nicknames 
JOIN first_names on fname = upper(name)
WHERE groupi = (SELECT nn.groupi FROM nicknames AS nn WHERE name = 'john') AND name != 'john' 
;
```